# Shadow copy referencing invalid volume from symboliclink when using TrueCrypt

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, symbolic-link, volume-shadow-copy

I recently replaced my motherboard after the last one failed (was shorting and causing random reboots).  I'm sure this was *not* healthy for the machine, and that a clean install would do wonders, but I'd like to fix the current install.

That aside, I've been tracking down a pair of errors in the application log.

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Error calling a routine on a Shadow Copy Provider {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}. Routine details IVssSnapshotProvider::QueryVolumesSupportedForSnapshots(ProviderId,29,...) [hr = 0x80042302, A Volume Shadow Copy Service component encountered an unexpected error.
>   Check the Application event log for more information.
>   ].
>
> Operation:    Query volumes supported by this provider
>
> Context:    Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>   Snapshot Context: 29

Followed by

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine Error calling CreateFile on volume '\?\Volume{f4bda86e-049d-11e1-9255-bcaec56690a1}\'.  hr = 0x80070020, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This error is reproducible at command line, creating the two event log entries

```
C:\Windows\system32>vssadmin list volumes
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.

Error: The shadow copy provider had an unexpected error while trying to process
the specified command.
```

Using WinObj from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062), I have tracked down the global object.

> '\?\Volume{f4bda86e-049d-11e1-9255-bcaec56690a1}\' - SymbolicLink -
>   '\Device\HarddiskVolume8'

Running DISKPART, and running the command "list volume" within it lists volumes 0 through 6, there is not a HarddiskVolume8.

How can I remove this reference to HarddiskVolume8, and get shadow copy up and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was coming from TrueCrypt.  The solution is to have TrueCrypt "mount volumes as removable media" in preferences.